# How to report to Google Analytics a purchase made in a mobile app but paid offline, using Firebase SDK

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

TL;DR: In a native mobile app using Analytics integrated through Firebase SDK, how can I report a purchase paid offline, like Cash on Delivery?

We have a mobile app that was developed using the Analytics SDK and now ported do Firebase (since Google is sunsetting Analytics SDK).

Users can place a purchase on the app and pay it later, like Cash on Delivery.
We only report purchases that have been paid and, until this move, we were successful in doing so through the Measurement Protocol API. All we had to do was record the ClientID from Analytics SDK and send it along with the request once we had confirmation of payment.

Since we're no longer using Analytics SDK, we can no longer access the ClientID. In parallel, we moved to a App+Web property and measurement protocol doesn't appear to work there.

Answer (score 0):

Google now has a new version of the Measurement API that should be used for GA4 properties.
At the time of writing it is in alpha but we've been using it to send purchase events to Firebase.
Still not perfect as we now have the events but still no reporting under Ecommerce.